# What cause memory reservation

Tags: c++, windows, memory

I have an application written in c++ that reserved 1.2GB memory but only 600MB are committed.
The application use COM/DCOM, ADO.

I would ask you if you have any idea why so many memory are reserved and never committed?

Thanks

Comment: How many threads do you have running?

Comment: Is this (rather old) KB article applicable to your case http://support.microsoft.com/kb/193026 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The application might intentionally reserve a large region for some allocator and only commit smaller regions as they are actually needed. If that's the case - they won't be committed until you make the application actually ask the allocator for memory allocation and it does commit memory.

Comment: Thank do you know which allocator can do that?

Comment: @mathk: Our company has a very simple in-house allocator that behaves like that, so I guess almost any qualified developer could write one and it can be just anything so there're no chances to guess.

Comment: Ok the thing is that I am searching for VirtualAlloc in the entier project and I couldn't find one. Is there an other function to reserved memory?

Comment: @mathk: I'm not aware of any other functions like that. It might be some middleware (like ADO) or some third-party library that does memory reservation.

Comment: you are right it seems that the problem is ADO. By isolating only the ADO part we have 800MB memory reserved and only 7MB committed